# cannot connect to the bitbucket serve fatal error occurs

Tags: git, bitbucket

git push -u origin master

fatal: unable to access 'https://bozdoz@bitbucket.org/bozdoz/bozdoz/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Bad access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bad access" implies that something is preventing git (or, more precisely, cURL) from getting to Bitbucket. Check your proxy and firewall setup, both on your local system and on your local network, and ensure that traffic to bitbucket.org:443 is permitted.